# Terrain Quadtree LOD can't detect out where T-junctions appears that generates cracks

Tags: algorithm, webgl, terrain

I implemented a Quadtree that stores a single mesh of data with different LOD levels, where each four children have their own vertices and their corresponding indexes to the four corners(x0, y0, x1, y1 -> from top to bottom) that makes up their corresponding LOD level.

```
QuadTree.prototype.fillTree = function(currentNode, depth, currentBox, currentIndex) {
    if(depth === 0 || !currentBox.checkPartition())
        return;

    let node = {
        "vertices" : [],
        "lines" : [],
        "children" : [],
        "box" : currentBox
    };

    currentNode.push(node);

    currentBox.getVerticesCoord(this.cols, currentIndex).forEach((coord) => {
        this.getPlaneVertices(node.vertices, coord);
    });

    currentBox.getLinesCoord(this.cols, currentIndex).forEach((coord) => {
        this.getPlaneVertices(node.lines, coord);
    });

    currentBox.getPartitions().forEach((box, index) => {
        this.fillTree(node["children"], depth-1, box, index);
    });
};
```

I have also a checkFrustumBoundaries method where I calculate the minimum distance between a LOD level and the camera location [0, 0, 0] and also checks if it's visible by being within [-1, 1] range for all the coordinates by being multiplied by the projection matrix and divided by w.

Finally I have the method that selects needed LOD levels for the current state by finding the minimum distance between camera origins and their corresponding depth and all 4 children being checked if they are within the visible zone and store them into an array that will be rendered.

**Note:** That I want children to inherit the depth of their sibling with lowest Complexity level if he is ready to be rendered, thus I will always have a 4 four square with same LOD level.

```
QuadTree.prototype.readComplexity = function(projection, viewCamera, currentNode, currentIndex, currentDepth = 1) {
    let childrenToBeRendered = [];
    let minDepth = this.depth;

    currentNode.children.forEach((child, index) => {
        let frustumBoundaries = this.checkFrustumBoundaries(child.vertices, projection, viewCamera);

        if(frustumBoundaries.withinFrustum) {
            //Section is the 1.0/this.depth
            let depth = this.depth-Math.ceil(frustumBoundaries.minDistance/this.section);

            minDepth = Math.min(minDepth, depth);

            childrenToBeRendered.push({
                "child" : child,
                "index" : index
            });
        }
    });

    childrenToBeRendered.forEach((child => {
        if(minDepth <= currentDepth) {
            //Even complexity, or the others quarters inherits on of their siblings with lowest complexity level
            this.fetchLines(projection, viewCamera, child.child, currentDepth, child.index);
        } else if(minDepth > currentDepth) {
            //Needs more complexity because it's too near to camera origins
            this.readComplexity(projection, viewCamera, child.child, child.index, currentDepth+1);
        }
    }));
};
```

But here I stumbled on the biggest problem, it appears T-junctions are causing cracks between different LOD levels:

[image: T-junction]

I figured out that I could remove the cracks by disabling the vertices that make up the T-junction by using a stack and append to it the 2 vertices that makes a half diamond and use the following child where I use his vertex whose index is different from the previous two used. By cycling, starting from the top-left to top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left with a flag in case there is a LOD difference between the top-right and the left neighbor of him.

[image]

But before doing that, I need to know if the child's neighbors have less complexity or equal, thus if the child let's say is at top-left, I need to know if there is a LOD level at left and top that takes four times more space and by logic has less complexity.

How can I manage to do it, how can I reach for neighbors if they can be located at different quad-tree levels, if I try to use the node's box to generate the two neighbors' boxes and calculate their depth, I can't compare them with the node because during the selection process, there is the possibility that the neighbor inherited his siblings depth, thus the comparison will be wrong. But, if I chose to not use the rule of four, consequently I can't use the tactics of diamond selection I mentioned above.